# Do I need to call something after simplesamlphpInstance->logout() to logout?

Tags: saml-2.0, logout, simplesamlphp

When I try to logout I just call 
$simplesamlphpInstance->logout();

But nothing happens. Should I call something else to logout?

I use https://github.com/asasmoyo/yii-simplesamlphp-example as a basis.

Comment: Are you saying that the login session is active even after you call logut()?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Only if I use another browser it is logged out.